# linq.js: GroupBy(), then ToJSON()

Tags: javascript, json, linq.js

I'm new to linq.js. I'd like to do a `GroupBy()`, which is then converted to JSON. However, I'm getting back a string array.

```
var data = [ { "Gender":"M" }, { "Gender":"M" }, { "Gender":"F" } ];
var grouped_dt = Enumerable.From(data).GroupBy("$.Gender", "", 'key,e=>key+":"+e.Count()', "").ToJSON();
```

My result then looks something like this: `[ "M:2", "F:1" ]`, which hardly looks like JSON (furthermore it is a `string`; I can `alert()` it immediately).

Does anybody have any idea where in my syntax am I screwing up? A confession: the `data` is just a simplified version of the data that I am getting from my server via AJAX, but it is completely in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I'd need to specify a key for each value (following the actual JSON format).

```
var grouped_dt = Enumerable.From(data).GroupBy("$.Gender", "key,e=>{name:key,y:e.Count()}", "").ToJSON();
```

Having done this, I'd also need to

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(grouped_dt);
```

to convert it into a JSON object for use.