# basic reporting on javascript array by date?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of orders loaded in a javascript array and I would like to summarize this data based on date.  I want to show total orders for each day, and total amount each day.

Normally I would do this in .Net or in a Stored Procedure.  Kinda stumped as to how to approach this using javascript.  Can anyone point me in the proper direction.  I have a decent grasp of Javascript but have never had to deal with data manipulation in JS.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What does your data look like? What are the expected input & output formats?

Comment: Are you saying you need to execute function when the date occurs ? like a cron job. Like calculate stats at the end of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're accustomed to `LINQ`, you can have a look at [linqjs](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/). Then you can use functions similar to .NET's LINQ (including [GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017806/linq-js-groupby-then-tojson) to get daily totals).

Otherwise, you're looking at creating your own result set and aggregating the information yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work in progress:

```js
var orders, groups;

orders = [
    ['order 1', 20, new Date(2012, 0, 1)],
    ['order 2', 20, new Date(2011, 0, 1)],
    ['order 3', 20, new Date(2010, 0, 1)],
    ['order 4', 20, new Date(2012, 0, 1, 10, 10, 10)]
];

groups = groupByDay(orders);
printSummary(groups);

// groups = {
//     1262300400000: [order 3]
//     1293836400000: [order 2]
//     1325372400000: [order 1, order 4]
// }

function groupByDay (orders) {
    var i, d, l, groups;
    groups = {};
    l = orders.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        d = orders[i][2]; // date of current record
        d.setHours(0); // reset hours
        d.setMinutes(0); // reset minutes
        d.setSeconds(0); // reset seconds
        d = d.getTime(); // turn the date into a timestamp (year, month, day)
        if (!groups[d]) groups[d] = []; // use it as a group identifier
        groups[d].push(orders[i]); // populate the group
    }
    return groups;
}

function printSummary (groups) {
    var d, g, i, l, amount;
    for (d in groups) {
        g = groups[d];
        l = g.length;
        amount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            amount += g[i][1];
        }
        document.write(
            (new Date(+d)).toDateString() + ': ' + amount + '<br />'
        );
    }    
}
```

Comment: I'll give you +1 just for coming up with a brief demo. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie Haha, thanks, I have a boring day :D